# Server switch: Check DNS TTL values

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, migration, nslookup, dig

Can somebody let me know if from the below results from using dig https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/

What is the correct TTL value? as I see 2 different ones:

```
id 10958
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
mydomain.com. IN ANY
;ANSWER
mydomain.com. 2747 IN A 159.xxx.xxx.xx
mydomain.com. 20747 IN NS ns1.namecity.com.
mydomain.com. 20747 IN NS ns2.namecity.com.
mydomain.com. 2747 IN SOA ns1.namecity.com. hostmaster.namecity.com. 2017111500 43200 5400 2419200 3600
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the TTL you seek is the one with your A record response: 2747.

The others are for your NS records themselves.

e.g. the TTL for the A records for tidalmigrations.com is 60 seconds:

`;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tidalmigrations.com.   IN A`

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.5
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.57
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.39
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.17
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.48
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.74
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.88
tidalmigrations.com.    60 IN A 52.84.143.164

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tidalmigrations.com.    172800 IN NS ns-1013.awsdns-62.net.
tidalmigrations.com.    172800 IN NS ns-1459.awsdns-54.org.
tidalmigrations.com.    172800 IN NS ns-1957.awsdns-52.co.uk.
tidalmigrations.com.    172800 IN NS ns-70.awsdns-08.com.